# Replicate a Web Application in sharepoint 2010 to a different farm

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, web-application

I have to replicate an existing web application and build it on a different farm in a different SharePoint server (version 2010). I have never even created and configured a complete web application so far. Could anyone help on what all information I need to collect and how can I do this?
So far I have picked out that below things to be done,

1. Create a Web application in the second farm with the required account configuration
2. Take a backup of the databases from 1st webapp and restore it on the db server of second webapp.
3. Install the wsp solutions
4. Configure necessary services which are specifically created for those webapps.
5. IIS app pool configuration

The above could be wrong, please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps looks good, I would make sure following things.

1. As you are using the Database Mounting method, I would make sure that dev farm version level should be same or higher( mount contentDatabase will upgrade to higher version).
2. Web Applications configuration means, any change in web.config file, Object cache Settings(if configured), Authentication method
3. IIS bindings
4. when you will create the web app, app pool will be created so no change should required.

Comment: This info is useful. Could you please tell me what will happen to the sitecollections & Other sites? Will they reflect or do we need to create them after the webapplication is created?

Comment: You dont need to create the site collection, as you are restoring a Database? as soon as you mount the DB everything in it showed up. Please detach the old Database, which was created during the Webapplication creation process.

Comment: if it is helpful, please up vote?

Comment: I have prepared the plan to replicate the web applications. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Those are good steps. In order to mount your database to the new Web Application in the development environment, use `Mount-SPContentDatabase` on the dev SharePoint server. This will automatically assign the appropriate permissions to the restored Content Database.

I would install the WSP(s) prior to mounting the Content Database. Not strictly required, but it will give you a cleaner mount.

IIS Application Pools should not be adjusted directly.